# Flexbox image and text size are not same

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to make flexboxes with the same height and width by using:

```
flex: 1;
```

But it is not working as I thought, image box becomes bigger than text box.

Here I made little example:
https://jsfiddle.net/p3uowcdg/9/

Comment: In your example, the items *are* equal width and height. Add `.container>*{outline:1px solid red;}` to see this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `grid` layout:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}

.box-image {
  width: 100%;
}

.box-text {
  width: 100%;
}
```

#### Result

[image]